# React App heroku deployment failing in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, webpack, internet-explorer-11

I have a jquery/react web application that only fails when I try to access the heroku production deployment on IE 11.  When built locally, the app runs fine on IE 11.  All other browsers function as expected in both local and production environment.

The error I'm getting is 'SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier'.  It points to this line in my main.js, {var n=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};

I've attempted to add various polyfills to no effect.  The fact that this fails only in the production version and specifically on IE 11 confuses me. If you any insight or can even assist with some tips as to how to better debug in IE, it would be greatly appreciated as I'm accustomed to using just chrome developer tools.

Thanks.

Edit: here is the dependency portion of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"12factor-config": "^1.3.1",
"axios": "^0.17.1",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"consolidate": "^0.14.5",
"express": "^4.15.3",
"gsap": "^1.20.4",
"handlebars": "^4.0.10",
"hoek": "^5.0.3",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.5",
"marked": "^0.3.17",
"newrelic": "^4.2.0",
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"
},
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your code, a reference to the problem page, etc. You haven't provided enough information to help you with.

Comment: I'm looking for general solutions and debugging strategies for this problem, I'm not sure I can really give a code example at this time because I'm not sure where to start, maybe a list of dependencies will help?  To me, it looks like IE is pointing to an arbitrary line so I can't really tell you where the issue is located or the project code associated with it. I'm hoping this issue sounds familiar to some and can be diagnosed to some extent based on the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed the problem down to the 'gsap' dependency, for some reason this was breaking production on IE11.